# how do I unlock a file that should not be locked?

Tags: locking, file-rename, fclose

I am writing a program to manipulate image file names.  I load the image using IO.FileStream and close the filestream after loading the image into the image box, but if I try to now rename the original file I frequently get file locked error.  Nothing else is using this image.

This is how I load the image
Dim fs = New System.IO.FileStream("Original File Name", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
imgImage.Image = Image.FromStream(fs)
fs.Close()

This is the code I am using to try and rename the file
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("Original File Name", "New File Name")

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdgQR.png)

Why does this only work sometimes, more often than not it throughs up the exception?
Any suggestions for how to do this?

As I understand it FileStream having been opened and closed should not put a lock on the file at all.

I have put in code to see if the file is open and it does show the file is open but I cannot see what left it open or how to close it.

Try

Dim myStream As IO.FileStream

myStream = IO.File.Open("Original file name", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)

```
  myStream.Close()

  Debug.Print("File was not locked")
```

Catch Ex As Exception

```
 Debug.Print("File was locked")
```

End Try